Количество вставляемых объектов в таблицу не сходится с ID
Количество вставляемых объектов в таблицу не сходится с ID
Почему происходит такое) ?
Вставляю 201 элемент, в таблице 201, но последний с ID 256
using Z.Dapper.Plus;

List<MyString> myClasses = new();

for (int i = 1; i < 202; i++)
{
    myClasses.Add(new MyString($"Строка {i}"));
}

using var connection = DBConnection.CreateConnection();
DapperPlusManager.Entity<MyString>().Table("MyStrings");
await connection.BulkInsertAsync(myClasses);

public class MyString
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string String { get; set; }

    public MyString(string str)
    {
        String = str;
    }
}



А вы уже вставляли данные ранее? Доходили ли предыдущие данные до значений 200-255?

@Chaos_Sower Очищал до вставки с помощью TRUNCATE TABLE и после данный код

Есть возможность опробовать на чистовой таблице? Я вот работаю с MS SQL, и у меня тоже была проблема с тем, что даже после удаления строк ID для новых элементов сбивался. Что с этим делать — не знаю ‍♂️. Но как я понял — оно и не важно, ID нужен только самой СУБД, а программист управлять им и не должен

Когда вы выделяете память для какого-то объекта с помощью new, вас интересует адрес, по которому он размещён? Нет. Точно так же вас не должен интересовать id, выделенный для объекта в БД. / Айдишники не для человека, они для компьютера!

На вопрос невозможно ответить, не зная следующее: какая СУБД (MySQL, Postgres...), как  создана таблица, какая библиотека используется для вставки, какой код SQL выполнялся до этого?

@AlexanderPetrov да, действительно не важно, просто смутило подобное)
